# Is there any localization support available in spring-security-oauth2?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Spring-security provides support for localization.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#localization
I am looking for similar option for oauth2.

I have implemented token based authorization using spring-security-oauth2. Is there any support for localization in spring-security-oauth2 or please suggest me any other option?

I have checked official document but did not find anything on that.

For example I am getting below messages based on the scenarios, I want to provide localize support those messages.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "7896d62f-04ce-42ad-b7bc-bd2436b73f8b"
}

{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Token was not recognised"
}

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the OpenID Connect specification states:

> error_description
>
> OPTIONAL. Human-readable ASCII encoded text description of the error.

Thus, localisation would have to use some other field or mechanism.